# nginx.conf file for nginx-ingress controller is not getting updated with new ingress paths

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I updated my ingress paths from example.com to example.com/Dev however when I try to access 'example.com/Dev', I get redirected to example.com. The ingress gets updated but then I checked the .conf for the nginx-ingress controller and there the path wasn't getting updated from '/' to '/Dev'. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943845/10776363

Comment: what's your ingress yaml?